# Convert multiple ranges to single PDF, with ranges separated

Tags: excel, vba

I convert multiple ranges on different worksheets to a single PDF.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim vFile As Variant
    Dim sFile As String

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws1.PageSetup.PrintArea = "B2:K51"

    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    ws2.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A3:J52, J3:S52, S3:AE52"

    Worksheets(Array(ws1.Name, ws2.Name)).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
      Type:=xlTypePDF, _
      Filename:=vFile, _
      Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
      IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
      IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
      OpenAfterPublish:=False

    MsgBox "PDF file has been created."
End If

End Sub
```

The PrintArea range for ws2 creates a single range.

How do I separate the ranges so the output is three ranges instead of one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Export to PDF

- The solution inserts a new worksheet and copies the ranges to it. Then it exports the new worksheet to PDF and deletes the new worksheet.

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`** (where the command button is)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    exportToPDF
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Sub exportToPDF()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const Gap As Long = 0
    Const vFile As String = "F:\Test\Export.pdf"
    Dim Ranges1 As Variant
    Ranges1 = Array("B2:K51")
    Dim Ranges2 As Variant
    Ranges2 = Array("A3:J52", "J3:S52", "S3:AE52")
    
    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    
    ' Define worksheets.
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim ws3 As Worksheet
    Set ws3 = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    
    ' Copy ranges from first to third worksheet.
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim CurrRow As Long
    CurrRow = 1
    Dim j As Long
    Dim RowsCount As Long
    Dim ColsCount As Long
    For j = LBound(Ranges1) To UBound(Ranges1)
        Set rng = ws1.Range(Ranges1(j))
        rng.Copy
        ws3.Cells(CurrRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        ws3.Cells(CurrRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlFormats
        If ColsCount < rng.Columns.Count Then
            ColsCount = rng.Columns.Count
        End If
        CurrRow = CurrRow + rng.Rows.Count + Gap
    Next j
    
    ' Copy ranges from second to third worksheet.
    For j = LBound(Ranges2) To UBound(Ranges2)
        Set rng = ws2.Range(Ranges2(j))
        rng.Copy
        ws3.Cells(CurrRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        ws3.Cells(CurrRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlFormats
        If ColsCount < rng.Columns.Count Then
            ColsCount = rng.Columns.Count
        End If
        CurrRow = CurrRow + rng.Rows.Count + Gap
    Next j
   
    ' Export and close third worksheet.
    With ws3
        Set rng = .Range("A1").Resize(CurrRow - Gap - 1, ColsCount)
        rng.Columns.AutoFit
        .PageSetup.PrintArea = rng.Address
        .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                             Filename:=vFile, _
                             Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                             IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
                             IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                             OpenAfterPublish:=True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "PDF file has been created."
    
End Sub
```

**Populate Data (Standard Module)**

To quickly see what the code does:

- Create a workbook containing worksheets `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`.
- Copy all three codes appropriately.
- Run `populateData`.
- Run `exportPDF`.

**The Code**

```
Private Sub populateData()
    With [Sheet1!B2:K51]
        .Formula = "=ROW()&""|""&COLUMN()"
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End With
    With [Sheet2!A3:AE52]
        .Formula = "=ROW()&""|""&COLUMN()"
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 8
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this so clearly! Very appreciated.